# How do I add different colours to my tags in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I am learning html on notepad++. It would be great to see different tags in a different color as well as attributes in another color

Comment: The default color scheme for HTML/XML shows tags in one color and attributes in another. Do you mean a different color for each individual tag or attribute? That's not going to be possible. A tag is a tag, and an attribute is an attribute, but there's no difference between one tag and another as far as NP++ is concerned.

Comment: All the codes appear in white color against black background. But I want tags in one color say green and attributes in other color like yellow.

Comment: If you set the language to HTML (from the main menu, Languages), it syntax-highlights. At least (in NP++ v5.5), tags are in blue, attributes are in red, text is in black. (You can also just open an HTML file from disk, and it sets the language automatically.)